# Application does not have access to one or more requested data elements: [buyerInfo, shippingAddress]

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to request a restricted access token, but I get this error. Is something wrong with my request?

Request

POST https://sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com/tokens/2021-03-01/restrictedDataToken? HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
x-amz-access-token: X
x-amz-date: 20220330T131704Z
Authorization: X
Signature=X
Content-Type: application/json
Host: sellingpartnerapi-na.amazon.com
Content-Length: 116
Expect: 100-continue

{"restrictedResources":[{"method":"GET","path":"/orders/v0/orders","dataElements":["buyerInfo","shippingAddress"]}]}

Response:

{
"errors": [
{
"code": "InvalidInput",
"message": "Application does not have access to one or more requested data elements: [buyerInfo, shippingAddress]",
"details": ""
}
]
}

Answer (score -1):

You have to apply for restricted roles first :"Direct-to-Consumer Shipping,Tax Invoicing,Tax Remittance".
I called RDT by postman successfully, but I can't get buyer name with rdt by calling orders api.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).